# Where to I get the StandardServiceRegistryBuilder?

Tags: hibernate

Out of the following imports, the first two work fine and the last *cannot resolve symbol 'boot'*. What do I need to download to get that working? I tried searching Maven but there's no Hibernate library named anything with boot.

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
```

Comment: You need Hibernate 4.3.5 for this , download jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.5.Final

Answer (score 2):

## Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>     
</dependency>
```

## Java class:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

::
::
::

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    configuration.addResource("customer.hbm.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

    serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build(); 
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have added all the following hibernate dependencies to my pom.xml and it seam to be working now

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Hibernate Core 4.3.5 Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And in Gradle should be:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.5.Final'
```

Comment: Care to explain a bit more?

Comment: you are missing the jars or might be using unsupported versions. Adding the above dependencies should resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure that you have enabled auto-import if it is Intellij IDEA